# Can I split MIDI regions at program change events in Logic Pro X?

Tags: midi, logic-pro

First, have a screenshot:
[image: loadsaprogchanges.logicx]

The MIDI file I'm working with was generated by a tool which really likes program change events. While this is expected behavior for said tool, it makes the resulting file a pain to deal with in LPX.

This MIDI region has almost a thousand of these events (using 14 different program numbers total) and I'd like to split it at each of these events to separate all following notes (and volume/balance changes) into their own tracks for easier editing.

I tried writing a Scripter script that assigns all events following a program change event to another channel, which would allow me to use LPX's "Separate by MIDI channel" function, but apparently there's no way for Scripter (or any of the other MIDI FX plugins) to be applied destructively.

I also tried writing a Python script to go through the MIDI file and do the same thing, but I can't get it to output non-bogus data.

Do I have to split this region manually or is there an easier way?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: I didn't, sorry.

Comment: sounds like an interesting challenge, then :)

Answer (score 2):

maybe this open source project can help?

https://github.com/gocha/midisplit

Even if no binaries are available, it's easy to build with Visual Studio 2019, and it worked for me.

Best regards.